# GoogleTest SetArgReferee with vector<unique_ptr>

Tags: c++, googletest, unique-ptr

I have a function that takes a vector of unique_ptr:

```
void MyObject::myfunc(std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Foo>>& vec)
{
   std::unique_ptr<Foo> f(new Foo);
   vec.emplace_back(std::move(f));
}
```

I am trying to test with Google Test's `SetArgReferee` but I am getting `error: use of deleted function`.

What I have:

```
class MockMyObject : public MyObject {
public:
    MOCK_METHOD1(myfunc, void(std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Foo>>&));
};
```

And in my test:

```
MockMyObject mockObject;
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Foo>> vecToReturn;
EXPECT_CALL(mockObject, myfunc(_)).WillOnce(SetArgReferee<0>(vecToReturn));
```

What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

I ended up using this workaround:

```
class MockMyObject : public MyObject {
public:
    MOCK_METHOD1(callmyfunc, void(std::vector<Foo*>&));
    void myfunc(std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Foo>>& vec)
    {
        std::vector<Foo*> helperVec;
        callmyfunc(helperVec);
        for (const auto& ptr : helperVec) {
            vec.emplace_back(std::unique_ptr<Foo>(ptr));
        }
    }

};
```

And then setting the expectations on `callmyfunc` instead of `myfunc`:

```
MockMyObject mockObject;
std::vector<Foo*> vecToReturn;
vecToReturn.push_back(new Foo);
EXPECT_CALL(mockObject, callmyfunc(_)).WillOnce(SetArgReferee<0>(vecToReturn));
```

Comment: Thanks for answering this, it has helped me greatly! I'm curious if you ever came up with a better way of doing this? I don't know if the GMock library had released some sort of patch in the last year for handling this?

Comment: Hi Andy, no, I haven't had any updates here. As far as I'm aware, this workaround is still needed.